# element is invalid, The Enumeration constraint failed in my input xml message

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

Below is the XML request file and I do testing by using this file in a BizTalk map  :

[image: please click this link for xml file request]

When I do map test I got below this error, when i checked source schema data type of the element "TDID" is string,and input file got string only but I got this error when testing BizTalk map

> Input validation error: "The '//Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ORDERS05/ZORDERS05/731:TDID' element is invalid - The value 'ZSID' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/ORDERS05/ZORDERS05/731:E1EDKT1_TDID'" - The Enumeration constraint failed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the field TDID is only a string data type? Seems that it is a string with restriction, probably the data type is an enumeration and not a basic string. If you validate this XML with the origin schema, I guess you'll get the same validation error. 
You can generate an instance of this origin schema and you'll see a different result after validation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply xurxo garcia.
I checked just now that field is restriction under derived type property. could you pleas suggestion me how solve this issue.

Comment: If you have a restriction in the input schema, your only solution is that the message arriving matches this schema. You should warn the system which is sending this message about the problem. And if finally the message is correct, you'll need to update the schema with the new values.